# How to build Emacs29 with tree-sitter without sudo

Tags: build, tree-sitter, emacs-29

Here are the commands I'm running

First I install `tree-sitter`

```
make PREFIX=${HOME}/.tree-sitter
make PREFIX=${HOME}/.tree-sitter install
```

This populates `~/.tree-sitter` directory

```
├── include
│   └── tree_sitter
│       └── api.h
└── lib
    ├── libtree-sitter.a
    ├── libtree-sitter.so -> libtree-sitter.so.0.0
    ├── libtree-sitter.so.0 -> libtree-sitter.so.0.0
    ├── libtree-sitter.so.0.0
    └── pkgconfig
        └── tree-sitter.pc
```

Then I install emacs

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-29.1.tar.gz
tar -xf emacs-29.1.tar.gz
cd emacs-29.1

TREE_SITTER_CFLAGS=-I~/.tree-sitter/include TREE_SITTER_LIBS="-L~/.tree-sitter/lib -ltree-sitter" ./configure --prefix=${HOME}/emacs --bindir=${HOME}/.local/bin --with-tree-sitter --with-gnutls=ifavailable

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.tree-sitter/lib make install
```

And the last install command errors out with

```
  CC       emacs.o
In file included from emacs.c:142:
treesit.h:27:10: fatal error: tree_sitter/api.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <tree_sitter/api.h>
```

Comment: Was following this guide https://blog.markhepburn.com/posts/experimenting-with-the-built-in-treesitter-support-in-emacs/

Comment: Well does `api.h` actually exist in `~/.tree-sitter/include/tree_sitter`?

Comment: What OS are you using and what does sudo have to do with your question?

Comment: What I actually did is build emacs inside a container while mounting certain volumes and was able to run afterwards `docker run -ti -v ~/repos/tree-sitter:/tree-sitter -v ~/emacs:${HOME}/emacs -v ~/.local/bin:/emacs-bin jammy`

Comment: That is a ridiculous amount of complexity to solve a trivial problem. What OS are you using, again? And what does sudo have to do with anything? Why aren’t you just installing Emacs (and, if necessary, treesitter) the normal way for your OS?

Comment: @db48x because some OSn don't include 29.1 with treesitter and native compilation of course.

Comment: You should use 'make V=1' to see what include flags are actually used. And you may have to adjust your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to include the location of `tree-sitter.pc`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using documented approach? eg

> ./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-tree-sitter --with-native-compilation

then

> make -j$(nproc)

and finally sudo to install into usr/local

> sudo make install

treesitter is included in 29 afaik.

Comment: probably because OP is trying to do it without sudo, of course